# javascript/jquery trigger a text change event on a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there anyway to trigger the textChanged event in a text area using javascript or jquery ?

I want the textchange event to occur once the page is loaded.

Comment: do you want to trigger it manually?

Comment: To help better address your issue, what do you plan to do with the text area data if a textChanged event occurs?

Comment: sorry guys, yes i wanted to trigger a textchanged event manually

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('textarea').trigger('change');
});
```

But this will only trigger if the change event was added through jQuery. If not you could try:

```
$('textarea').get(0).change();
```

Comment: And if it's not a textarea but contenteditable div? Then the "$('textarea').get(0).change();" brings Uncaught TypeError: textarea.get(...).change is not a function

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
$(function(){
    $("textarea").change()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have to use the event `input` since my textarea used as emoji field.

For ex.

```
$('textarea').trigger('input');
```